# string comparison with user build string-like type

Tags: c++

Normally you can compare strings..

```
if (var1 == "a string") ...
```

But when I declare my own class with the conversion operator, like this :

```
class my_type {
   operator std::string() const { ... };
   ....
}
```

Now this :

```
 std::string var1("a string");
 my_type x("a string");
 if (x == "a string") ....
 if (x == var1) ....
```

does not work.. i.e....

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’
```

Of course this works :

```
 if ((std::string) x == var1) ....
```

But I want it to happen w/o explicitly casting.
why does not c++ convert my_type to string for comparison..
How can I force it to do this w/o implementing the "==" operator itself ?
The same goes for the other comparison operators.

thank you

PS> Btw if I implement operator which convert my_type to numbers(it is OK for my type)...like :

```
 operator double() const { ... };
```

the comparison with numbers work ok, I don't need to implement ==,etc.....

Comment: I guess the `str` in `operator str::string()` is a typo?

Comment: @nyarlathotep: Ahh, indeed, it should be `str::stding`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12408752/673730), this isn't about implicit casts, but of how `operator ==` behaves on strings.

I however suggest you overload `operator ==` for your class and not rely on an implicit conversion.

Comment: Does this answer OP's question whether it's possible to make it work without an explicit cast?

Comment: @user396672 no, your code is invalid. You're not allowed to extend the `std` namespace.

Comment: @Luchian: athough it compiles under VC2010 and on Ideone. I only illustrate the matter, i can introduce the operator in the global namespace with the same result

Comment: @Luchian: ... and regardles of moral acceptability of std extensions it illustrates that implicit conversions work on classes for operator overloads

Answer (score 2):

The conversion doesn't work because operator == for strings is a templated operator (function template), not an overload (see, for instance, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp for operator == declaration).

For function templates argument types must match parameters exactly (without any implicit conversions).
To illustarte the difference, let's introduce an overload << operator on strings:

```
#include <string>

struct X
{
    operator std::string() {return "X";}
};


std::string operator << (std::string const& s1, std::string const& s2)
{
  return s1+s2;
}

int main()
{
    X x;
    x<<std::string("bla"); // compiles fine
}
```

It compiles fine.

Comment: You're right, it's not about implicit conversion, but how `operator ==` works between strings. I wouldn't recommend overloading it though.